# Using GPS to two location (Position 1 to 2) , OnLocation Changed

Tags: java, android, distance

I am targeting of using Android 2.2 to find distance using GPS however there are some problem in regarding my on Location changed. Previously, I put my code at On click listener and it does not work well. I manage to get the distance only after pressing the start and stop button after a numerous times.

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
    {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {  
            if(originalCoordinates!=null){
                coordinates1 = getGPS();
                gpsEnd=coordinates1;
                double d = distFrom(originalCoordinates[0],originalCoordinates[1],gpsEnd[0],gpsEnd[1]);
                totalDistanceTravel+=d;
                disTrav.setText(Double.toString(d));
                txtViews.setText("" + coordinates1.length + " new counts!!!" + coordinates1[0] + "," + coordinates1[1] );


            }   
            if(coordinates!=null)
                {
                    double[] coordinatesPrev=coordinates;
                    txtView.setText("" + coordinates.length + " counts!!!" );
                    //double d = distFrom(coordinatesPrev[0],coordinatesPrev[1],coordinates[0],coordinates[1]);
                    //totalDistanceTravel+=d;
                }
                else
                {
                    coordinates = getGPS();       
                    gpsOrg=coordinates;
                    if(originalCoordinates == null){
                        originalCoordinates = gpsOrg;
                        coordinates1 = getGPS();
                        txtView.setText("" + originalCoordinates.length + " original counts!!! "  + originalCoordinates[0] + "," + originalCoordinates[1] );


                    }
                    //txtView.setText("" + coordinates.length + " counts" );
                }
        startButton.setEnabled(true);
        }
```

Comment: what does this actually mean..
<I manage to get the distance only after pressing the start and stop button after a numerous times.>
Be specific, it'll make easy to understand. What do you want and where/what is the problem?

Comment: Currently, i have to calculate the distance between a starting point and a ending point. My approach is using of a start button and a stop button. When the start button is tapped, the location (latitude, longitude) will be captured. Same goes for the stop button. From these 2 points, the distance can be calculated.

Comment: Currently, i have to calculate the distance between a starting point and a ending point. My approach is using of a start button and a stop button. When the start button is tapped, the location (latitude, longitude) will be captured. Same goes for the stop button. From these 2 points, the distance can be calculated. But now i want the calculation of distance to keep running as i'm travelling which means the distance will keep increasing as i travel instead of capturing the latitude and longitude of the starting point and end point.

Comment: In order to do this, the calculation of distance have to be in the 'onLocationChanged' method. I'm not supposed to use webservice.

Comment: sorry, posted comment on wrong question..:(
check the answer...

Answer (score 0):

dear do it like this.

1. Switch on GPS of your device
2. Wait until it get connected to a satellite.
3. Make a flag like booelan detecting_position.
4. Set it true on start button.
5. OnLocationChange Listner, check if flag is true, then get the
   points using location.getLat,and getLong... and save them.
6. Here you can do a trick, initialize start location variables with
   null, and check if startPosition is null then on first iteration of
   location listner set long and lat as start location, in further
   location change iterations set long and lat to stop_location
   variables.
7. Once you tap the stop button set flag to false.
8. Now you have both start and end position. Use the distance formula
   to calculate distance.

Comment: Hi, this is what I am suppose to do but I am unable to do it.

Comment: Hi Awais, I have updated my codes on top but dont seem working. I'm trying on a Samsung Nexus Phone.

Answer (score 0):

first of all take activity and do like below

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
    {

```
Button btnStart = null;
Button btnStop = null;

Context context = null;
Button btnTouch = null;

float distance ;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    context = this;

    btnStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
    btnStop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStop);

    btnStart.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnStop.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    Intent i =  new Intent(context, MyService.class);
    if(v.getId() == R.id.btnStart)
    {
        startService(i);
    }
    else if(v.getId() == R.id.btnStop)
    {
        distance = MyService.final_distance;
        stopService(i);
    }
   }
```

}


then take one service and put our logic for location change in this service.i have use service because service run in background continue and look for location change when location is update.


    `public class MyService extends Service implements LocationListener
    {`

```
 public static float final_distance = 0.0f;

private float distance = 0.0f;

private double old_latitude = 0.0;
private double old_longitude = 0.0;
private double new_latitude = 0.0;
private double new_longitude = 0.0;



LocationManager locationManager = null;


float[] result = null;

@Override    
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
{
    return null;    
}        
@Override    
public void onCreate() 
{

    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0L, 0.0f, this);

    result = new float[3];
}    
@Override    
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) 
{

} 
@Override 
public void onDestroy() 
{
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
{

    if(old_latitude == 0.0 && old_longitude == 0.0)
    {
        old_latitude = location.getLatitude();
        old_longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    new_latitude = location.getLatitude();
    new_longitude = location.getLongitude();



    Location.distanceBetween(old_latitude, old_longitude, new_latitude, new_longitude, result);

    distance = final_distance +result[0];//distance in meters between two locations 

    final_distance = distance;

    old_latitude = new_latitude;
    old_longitude = new_longitude;
}
@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) 
{

}
@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) 
{

}
@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) 
{

}
```

}


and also add  uses permission android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION in android manifest.xml

Hope this may help you

Comment: why my context = this; have error. The error is can not solve a variable. :(

Comment: have you extends Activity? like i have do in my code please go through same and also one thing declare this statement  my context = this; in activity's onCreate() method and if possible please post your code that show error whole code not only that statement.

Comment: try using context = getApplicationContext();
Rest of the Code seems correct.

Also I didn't implemented it using service. Try it in basic activity and see if works.

...............implements OnClickListener,LocationListener in basic activity.